# Organising REST API web service build using Python Eve

Tags: python, api, mongodb, eve

I am trying to build a REST API web service using Python Eve. I have experience in using Lithium (PHP framework) and Ruby on Rails but I am struggling to figure out the proper folder structure to use with Python Eve. Any suggestion on where to put my models and controllers (mostly pre / post hooks).

Comment: In this question I am asking for suggestions to implement more complex model and controller using Python-Eve. I don't think it comes under question asking for "opinion". Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Eve demo](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve-demo) source code? Should be enough to get you started. Hooks can then be added to the `run.py` script, see the [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks). A more complex application (not so much at this point in time) is [Adam](https://github.com/CIR2000/adam), still a work in progress though.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, Eve looks very promising, but my application is a bit more complex to put all the pre / post hooks in 1 file.

Comment: Oh but the running script is just a Python module, so you can organize you application in different modules/packages as needed.

Comment: @NicolaIarocci Thanks for the ref. I am using Adam as a boilerplate for my project, and having the same issues to organize a lot of pre/post hooks. Currently I am trying to place them in each domain model file, and I am wondering if you can point me to some examples/references that eve would recommend? Thanks!